# Tor Browser Bundle: Are files downloaded using Tor?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

Does the browser bundle already route downloads through Tor or do I have to use Tails to achieve this?

Comment: Related question: [Is tor browser bundle safe for downloading?](http://superuser.com/q/605353/61370)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. TBB downloads files through Tor.